# PHP script send several emails when Outlook 2010 downloads an image

Tags: php, outlook

Using Outlook 2010, I insert an image into a message that I intend to send.  I insert the image’s URL (that points to a PHP file shown below) followed by  “Insert” “Link to File”.

The image is displayed correctly in the message area of the mail.

However, the PHP script sends several emails instead of a single one when the image is downloaded and displayed in the Outlook message area.  It looks like Outlook is making serval retries to load the image.

Please help me how to fix this problem and make the script send only a single email. The PHP code is provided below:

```
<?php

// Show image in browser/email client.

$logo = "http://www.example.com/logo.gif"; // Set image Full Path

readfile($logo);

// Send a test email
    ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    $from = "abc@isp1.com";
    $to = "def@isp2.net";
    $subject = "test email";
    $message = "This is a test to check image download";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to,$subject,$message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: whats the access log say?

Comment: This is generally the normal behaviour for email clients as they tend to fetch images when they need it rather than how browsers would cache images etc. You could look into setting a cookie so that if there is no cookie set then send the email and then set the cookie.

Comment: or log the first hit. check the log before sending again

Comment: and generally speaking, outlook doesn't fetch external resources unless the user authorizes it. normally it should never reach out to your server to read that image in the first place.

Comment: if the email is just to test its working -well there is no issue, turn of the email

Comment: @Dagon

Where do I find the access log?

Comment: @Dagon
 
If I log the first hit, and send the email, I will need to reset it after a delay because I will not be able to download the image again when outlook is asking for it. When I implemented a delay, the image would download after the delay which is not good. Any suggestions?

Comment: @JamieBicknell

 
I probably did not explain myself well enough. I do want the email to fetch the image and I do want the script to send a notification that the image was loaded. I narrowed down my problem in a larger program to this simple example to make it easy on you to propose a way to reduce the emails sent (when the image is fetched) to a single email. Jamie suggested to set a cookie, however I am not sure if I can set it when the image is loaded by the outlook program and not by a traditional visitor to the page. –  Menachem 22 mins ago

Comment: You could limit the number of emails sent by IP address. Then once an IP has pinged that image URL, log the IP and don't send the email again for that IP address.

Comment: @JamieBicknell
Thank yo for your reply. The problem is that I do want Outlook (with the same IP) to download more images however not immediately. I believe that a delay of 3 seconds will do the job because the PHP script is sending the unwanted multiple emails in a burst. However, when I tried to add  a delay using the Sleep (3) function, the image would not load until the delay is complete although I had the image code before the delay.

Comment: seems a bit odd with what you're doing with email here

Comment: Ok, so add the emails to a queue in a database and then process the email queue via a CRON job.